# Refreshing a page with JavaScript href for Google Translate in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

This href code, I found online somewhere, works in Chrome, Edge, and Opera but it doesn't work correctly in Firefox or Safari.

I'm using this code to refresh my page (websyn.html) into a user selected Google translated version of my page example websyn.html#googtrans(fr). In Firefox it only refreshes the page and drops the #googtrans(fr) and stays untranslated.

I'm a newbie to coding, so any help is amazing.
Any ideas?

```
 <a href="http://www.geocities.ws/pidu87/websyn.html#googtrans(fr)" onclick="window.location.reload(true);" target="_self">Français</a>
```

I want the page to reload as websyn.html#googtrans(fr) but in Firefox it reloads as websyn.html and not translated.

UPDATE 1/1/2019 this href doesn't work in Safari on an iPhone either....

**UPDATE 1/2/2019 I found the fix online!!!!**

```
<a href="?dummy=$random#googtrans(fr)">Français</a>
```

The above href works in all browsers!!!

Comment: Works fine for me in firefox (after fixing the formatting). Not sure if you copied your code wrong, but the left angle bracket is missing at the start of you anchor tag and the ending `</a>` is missing

Comment: Sorry this was my first post my original code had the brackets, I thought I had to remove them to post the code.... In Firefox my translate links works on your PC?

Comment: Well I don't think it works actually... but it doesn't seem to work in any browser. It's always english in Chrome too

Answer (score 0):

You're refreshing the page onclick, so it's taking the current URL and just reloading that. Remove onclick from your link.

```
<a href="http://www.geocities.ws/pidu87/websyn.html#googtrans(fr)" target="_self">Français</a>
```

Comment: You had me so excited to try this! Didn't work. Your basic html link code doesn't work in any browser. The page has to be reloaded or refreshed to be translated.

Comment: Works fine for me. If I go to this page, it's in French http://www.geocities.ws/pidu87/websyn.html#googtrans(fr)

Comment: I FOUND THE FIX!!!! <a href="?dummy=$random#googtrans(fr)">Français</a>. It works in all browsers!!! Thank you for trying to help.